# Keep value in input under 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, what I want to do here is to keep the value in an `input` element a non-zero digit (`0<x<=9`). Here is my tag:

```
<input type="number" class="cell">
```

I have tried several JavaScript ideas, but none of them seem to work. I am using jQuery 3.2.1, BTW.

Comment: did you try min max attribute of input?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Specifying_minimum_and_maximum_values

Comment: @TalhaAbrar `max` attribute won't prevent user from typing unwanted number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for:

```html
<input type="number" class="cell" min="0" max="9" pattern="\d{0,9}">
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! +1.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example.

```js
$('input[type=number]').keyup(function(e) {
  var key = e.key
  if (/[0-9]/.test(key)) {
    e.target.value = key
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" class="cell" min="0" max="9" value="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/pj0L78sm/3/

```js
$('input[type="number"]').attr({
 max: 10,
  min: 0
});


$('input[type="number"]').keydown(function(e){
 var value = $(this).val() + (parseInt(String.fromCharCode(e.which)) || 0);
 if(e.which != 8 && (parseInt(value) < 0 || parseInt(value) > 10)  || e.which === 189){
   e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="cell">
```

I have kept limit as 0 to 10 and also used jQuery 3.2.1 in jsFiddle.

Comment: Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/pj0L78sm/3/ . Let me update the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```js
$('input[type="number"]').on('keyup click', function(){
 if($(this).val() > 9){
   $(this).val(9);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="cell">
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use **input** event:

```js
$('[type=number]').on('input', function(e) {
    if (this.value > 9) {
        this.value = this.value.split('').pop();
    }
    if (this.value <= 0) {
        this.value = 1;
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<input type="number" class="cell">
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow a number from `1` to `9`, all you have to do is disallow anything with more than two numbers, i.e. a lenght over 1.

To disallow zero, prevent the default action when a zero is pressed

```js
$('.cell').on('keydown', function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(1);
    if (e.which === 48 || e.which === 96) e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="cell">
```